# Why doesn't a code compiled in Linux run on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, unix

I simply mean to say that if both the OSs run on the same hardware, and an executable file contains 0s & 1s in machine language only, then why do we have to re-compile for each of them and not just change the extension of executable files, like *.out to *.exe to run the code?

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre votre raisonnement.

Comment: I wonder if you have ever let anyone write an answer to such a question thoroughly. Not that we are forcing everyone to write an answer to it. Free will, ever heard of it? What do you expect of us now, should we go to Quora then? 2 mins and [duplicate][closed]? Even that question is not having a proper answer to it. Not everyone is as smart as you, some of us here are beginners too!

Comment: I think that the other question has been answered thoroughly enough. If there's a particular point you did not understand, perhaps you should ask about it, rather than ask the same question again. Furthermore, that question was tagged as off topic, which implies that yours is too. Please consider reformulating your question. Thank you!

Comment: All right then, if that's the case, then I take my words back.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Linux executable files have different format. Even if they had the same format, the APIs provided by the two operating systems are different.

Apple faced a similar problem when they were moving from PowerPC to x86. Their solution was [Universal Binaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary). These appeared as a single executable to the user; however, under the hood they were two separate binaries bundled together.

Answer (score 0):

To answer in a similar vein - because the OS interprets the contents of the file differently. Looks for different things in different locations in the fileheader and so on... 
So Windows would try to interpret a linux binary as a PE and fail

Comment: So they don't just put it in the RAM and let the CPU handle the rest. Is it?

Comment: Nope. Not that simple :) The programs could also make requests to the OS e.g. DoX() and the other OS may not even have that API call or have a different name for it. Calling conventions: how parameters are passed to functions/subroutines.. there are a lot of details that the OS hides the user from.

Comment: So I need to learn about OSs more. Not that simple. Thanks. :)